# Converting text to speech on an azure web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-web-app-service, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I have a simple web application that uses [System.Speech](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer(v=vs.110).aspx) to dynamically generate speech and serve it back to the browser.

Unfortunately, this technique will not work in an azure website.  I'm struggling to find an alternative way to generate my speech.

I've tried half a dozen alternatives that I have found and most are too simple or use System.Speech under the hood.  To simple meaning that they pretty much only take a string and give no control over things like the gender of the voice, speed, pitch etc.

I'm looking for a way to generate the speech that offers at the minimum 2 distinct voices that I can switch between. 
It would be nice if I could control pitch, rate, and volume or even mix in pre-recorded text like with System.Speech.

Of course if there is a way to get System.Speech to work in azure that would be ideal but that seems unlikely.

Comment: Use [Microsoft's Text to Speech API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/speechapis/speechapis/) then. You could see [live demo here](https://www.projectoxford.ai/demo/speech#text2speech)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Microsft's [Speech API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/speechapis/speechapis/) instead?